# android app to load second activity has issue with mainactivity.java file

Tags: java, android, android-activity

there are four six involved: MainActivity.java, Main2Activity.java, activity_main.xml, activity_main2.xml, content_main.xml, content_main2.xml
when attempting to compile get an error with mainactivity.java which goes error class, enum expected. code follows: 
    `package com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve;

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.content.Intent;
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Button button;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NewActivity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
   }

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
    }

   public class NewActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button button;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NewActivity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
    }`
```

the manifest contains both MainActivity and NewActivity2 in it both in the same package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change the name from NewActivity2 to Main2Activity. If this process doesn't work, please put the code of your android Manifest in this post to we analyze it better.

The androidManifest.xml get the name of the file to work, that in your case is Main2Activity, so the name of your activity must be the same as your file's name.

Att.

Comment: did that. good suggestion. changed name in manifest and java files as well. errors now are dupicate class in Main2Activity and other error is symbol variable activity-main missing

Comment: Thx for the feedback, bro! If ou have any problem you can ask me that we will find the solution together! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a formatting error in NewActivity2.Remove the last line with braces of the onCreate() method of NewActivity2, and you're good to go. Also, did u declare NewActivity2 in Manifest? You mentioned MainActivity2 instead.

```
public class NewActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                NewActivity2.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}); <------ Remove this line and it will be fixed
```

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I used by mistake the name NewActivity2 instead of Main2Activity. I fixed this in the manifest and in the mainactivity.java. now trying to compile gives error class Main2Activity public should be in a file Main2Activity. It is. Here is excerpt my file main2activity.java 'public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);'

Comment: and it says symbol variable activity_main missing

Comment: Rename the file 'main2activity.java' to 'Main2Activity.java'

Comment: In which file is it throwing the error about activity_main?

Comment: did the rename. thanks so much. errors are in MainActivity.java. have a doubt. is it a problem if I have two public classes in same file? I clicked the tick mark on this page. here is my Main2Acivity.java file [code]
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

Comment: I changed the second public class to just class not to have two public classes in same file. now error is duplicate class (in my package) in Main2Activity.java in this latter file I have [code]public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity[/code]

Comment: You cannot have two public classes in the same file. Can you edit the answer and include your Main2Activity.java, error message?

Comment: I marked as accepted as it solved one issue. there are others. I have removed the second public class as you are correct. two public classes in same file no good. the only error I get now is cannot find symbol variable activity_main,

Comment: You'll have to include more information if you want help. Please edit your question to include only relevant information related to the error. The only possible explanation I can guess with the info provided is that the file is missing or has a different name.

Comment: I ended up removing the second public class (as I learned a java file cannot have two different public classes in it) and it compiled fine. created a signed app and tried it in my mobile device. the idea is a button on the first activity to load a second activity. however when this button is clicked the app crashes. -- I was trying to provide the stacktree output so you can see where the error is however there is a limit to the size of this comment. so I cannot do it. the stacktree output is long. would my jave file help?

Comment: not stacktree pardon, but stack trace. sorry about that!

Comment: Edit you question and post it there

Comment: since then compiled the app. made a signed release but when installed in mobile device crashes when the button to load second activity is clicked. tried a logcat but crash info not shown. will try logcat again changing vervose to debug.

Comment: updated Studio but no logcat output says unable to locate adb

Comment: My app compiles fine. When run in mobile device crashes when button to load second activity is clicked (SEE MORE). there are  six files involved: MainActivity.java, Main2Activity.java, activity_main.xml, activity_main2.xml, content_main.xml, content_main2.xml . plus I have a lengthy logcat file using an emulator. this platform does not seem to have file upload abilities. and in the space of one comment not possible to display all these files. is there one key file to help resolve this crash?

Comment: You don't have to include the details in the comment. Edit the answer and include it there. Without the logcat output, it is very difficult to debug the issue. Change the logcat to show only errors. And then check the stacktrace from the top until you find the file and the line number at which the issue is being caused.

Comment: I configured logcat for debug not verbose. I don't see any relevant output. I would like to try developer toos. my moble is connected. it has developer tools activated. it is recognized by my PC. in device manager it shows. 
when opening the console in Chrome I see on the right side html output and tabs such as elements, console, sources. how do I see my mobile device and the app I wish to debug? I will submit logcat output next...

Comment: Thread[1,tid=1244,Native,Thread*=0xb4034500,peer=0x12c35100,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so"
Thread[1,tid=1244,Native,Thread*=,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so"
09-06 16:16:21.865 1244-1244/? E/EmojiFactory_jni: Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: an emulator via AS. in Android Studio running debug  set  breakpoint at button click event handler in MainActivity.java. 
the results:[code] 
this = {MainActivity@4121} 
savedInstanceState = null 
button = {AppCompatButton@4122} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{9a56624 VFED..C.. ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0c006e app:id/MyButton}" 
mBreakStrategy = 0 
mLinksClickable = true 
mListeners = null 
mMaxMode = 1 
mIgnoreNextUpEvent = false 
mInContextButtonPress = false 
mInputEventConsistencyVerifier = null 
[/code] unnecessary lines removed

Comment: I'm assuming there is a problem with the emulator configuration. The stack trace shows problems with the native libraries. I'm assuming you are not using NDK. Im sorry. I have no clue if the emulator configuration is not the cause.

Comment: I do not use C nor C==

Comment: I do not use C nor C++. my app is java and AS type code. but thanks for having a look. yes you are correct I do not use NDK

Comment: without an emulator I could not go forward with a debug in Android Studio. I use the emulator AS suggests. my phone in Samsung Galaxy j6

Comment: you can debug on your phone as well.

Comment: my phone does not have app debug nor app developement platforms. the emulator I use is Nexus One AP123 480x800hdpu Api 23 Android 6, My phone is Android 8 Samsung J6. The Android Studio creates an apk which it runs on my phone and debugs. CAN YOU SEE WHY MY APP CRASHES?

Comment: Enable developer options in your phone. https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-get-developer-options-on-android/

Comment: Also, if you click on debug button in android studio instead of run. You will get teh stacktrace for verbose and debug on your phone then

Comment: I have developer options on im my phone but it does not display info on app crashes. Phone is Android 8. Ran debug on AS. output gives [code]this = {MainActivity@4121} 
savedInstanceState = null
button = {AppCompatButton@4122} "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{9a56624 VFED..C.. ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0c006e app:id/MyButton}"
 mBackgroundTintHelper = {AppCompatBackgroundHelper@4161} 
  mBoring = null
 mBreakStrategy = 0
 mBufferType = {TextView$BufferType@4164} "NORMAL"
 mDeferScroll = -1
 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1985649116
[/code]

Comment: thanks all. the app now compiles and runs fine. just one detail. when app launched the keyboard pops up. tried to supress this with [code]android:focusableInTouchMode="false"[/code] in edit text in content_main.xml to no avail

Comment: View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (view != null)
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0); And please do vote the answer up/accept if it helped.